# Match two different 'date' types in R

Tags: r

I have two datasets which I want to match up based on date, but they have the dates formatted in different ways.

The two formats are:

```
9/11/2012
20120911
```

I know I can convert the first one to a standard format by doing the following:

```
# convert date info in format 'mm/dd/yyyy'
strDates <- c("01/05/1965", "08/16/1975")
dates <- as.Date(strDates, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

What can I do with the second date format to make it a standard type?

I tried this but it doesn't quite work:

```
as.Date(data$DATE[1],"%Y%m%d")
```

Comment: This works for me: `as.Date("20120911", format = "%Y%m%d")`. You might want to check what pops out from `data$DATE[1]`.

Comment: Thanks for that. The column was formatted as numerical but the line only works on characters. I was able to fix it with as.Date(as.character(data$DATE[1]),"%Y%m%d")

Comment: Great! `str(the-object-you-want-to-do-something-with)` should be your among your close R friends.

Comment: The other situation where this will bite is mmddyyyy formatted dates and when these get read in as numeric, the leading "0"'s get lost and all the months from Jan to September get returned as NA's.

Comment: @aman88 when you say "The column was formatted as numerical" you actually mean factor instead of numerical.

Comment: Package lubirdate provides parsing ability for both numerical and character values. `library("lubridate")` then `ymd(20120911)`.